# Python 3.6 connection to MS SQL Server for large dataframe

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x

I am a new Python coder and also a new data scientist so please forgive any foolish sounding things here. I'll keep the details out unless anyone's curious but basically I need to connect to Microsoft SQL Server and upload a Pandas DF that is relatively large (~500k rows) and I need to do this almost every day as the project currently stands.

It doesn't have to be a Pandas DF - I've read about using odo for csv files but I haven't been able to get anything to work. The issue I'm having is that I can't bulk insert the DF because the file isn't on the same machine as the SQL Server instance. I'm consistently getting errors like the following:

> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL
>   Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'.
>   (156) (SQLExecDirectW)")

As I've attempted different SQL statements you can replace `IF` with whatever has been the first `COL_NAME` in the `CREATE` statement. I'm using SQLAlchemy to create the engine and connect to the database. This may go without saying but the `pd.to_sql()` method is just way too slow for how much data I'm moving so that's why I need something faster.

I'm using Python 3.6 by the way. I've put down here most of the things that I've tried that haven't been successful.

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import numpy as np    
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 1)), columns=list('test_col'))
address = 'mssql+pyodbc://uid:pw@server/path/database?driver=SQL Server'
engine = create_engine(address)
connection = engine.raw_connection()
cursor = connection.cursor()
# Attempt 1 <- This failed to even create a table at the cursor_execute statement so my issues could be way in the beginning here but I know that I have a connection to the SQL Server because I can use pd.to_sql() to create tables successfully (just incredibly slowly for my tables of interest)
create_statement = """
DROP TABLE test_table
CREATE TABLE test_table (test_col)
"""
cursor.execute(create_statement)
test_insert = '''
INSERT INTO test_table
(test_col)
values ('abs');
'''
cursor.execute(test_insert)

Attempt 2 <- From iabdb WordPress blog I came across
def chunker(seq, size):
    return (seq[pos:pos + size] for pos in range(0, len(seq), size))
records = [str(tuple(x)) for x in take_rates.values]

insert_ = """
INSERT INTO test_table
("A")
VALUES
"""

for batch in chunker(records, 2): # This would be set to 1000 in practice I hope
    print(batch)
    rows = str(batch).strip('[]')
    print(rows)
    insert_rows = insert_ + rows
    print(insert_rows)
    cursor.execute(insert_rows)
    #conn.commit() # don't know when I would need to commit

conn.close()

# Attempt 3 # From a related Stack Exchange Post
 create the table but first drop if it already exists
command = """DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test_table
CREATE TABLE test_table # these columns are from my real dataset
"Serial Number" serial primary key,
"Dealer Code" text,
"FSHIP_DT" timestamp without time zone,
;"""
cursor.execute(command)
connection.commit()

# stream the data using 'to_csv' and StringIO(); then use sql's 'copy_from' function
output = io.StringIO()
# ignore the index
take_rates.to_csv(output, sep='~', header=False, index=False)
# jump to start of stream
output.seek(0)
contents = output.getvalue()
cur = connection.cursor()
# null values become ''
cur.copy_from(output, 'Config_Take_Rates_TEST', null="")
connection.commit()
cur.close()
```

It seems to me that MS SQL Server is just not a nice Database to play around with...
I want to apologize for the rough formatting - I've been at this script for weeks now but just finally decided to try to organize something for StackOverflow. Thank you very much for any help anyone can offer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only need to replace the existing table, truncate it and use bcp utility to upload the table.  It's much faster.

```
from subprocess import call

command = "TRUNCATE TABLE test_table"
take_rates.to_csv('take_rates.csv', sep='\t', index=False)
call('bcp {t} in {f} -S {s} -U {u} -P {p} -d {db} -c -t "{sep}" -r "{nl}" -e {e}'.format(t='test_table', f='take_rates.csv', s=server, u=user, p=password, db=database, sep='\t', nl='\n')
```

You will need to install bcp utility (yum install mssql-tools on CentOS/RedHat).

Comment: Thanks Babu. Can you elaborate on where the command string is read by the call statement? Also I'm getting the following error in my test:
SQLState = 22005, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Invalid character value for cast specification

I've Google this some but can't figure out how to change the code you've put up to make it work. Any help would be appreciated! My test was done with integers but the actual tables I'll deal with will be all strings if that changes anything. Finally I am on a Windows machine if that also changes anything. Thanks so much!

Comment: Babu, I went into Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and manually changed the types of the columns to VARCHAR(8000) and the bcp call worked just fine! I'm going to try it with a real dataset I have and I'll post an update after. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry to blow-up the comments with real-time live updates... The data that I'll be uploading has dates involved and I need to try to get the date format uploaded correctly (ie, not uploading '2017-10-31' as a string). Can you please post a short example of specifying column types using the bcp call statement? Thank you so much again!

Comment: Typically you get the invalid value for cast when the csv file is parsed incorrectly and cast of type from csv to database column is incorrect.  Another frequent error is with String truncation if the size of the data for a column in csv is larger than database column size.  As long as data type in csv matches schema and the parsing of csv matches the columns correctly you should be good.  The -e option logs errors.  You can check the error file to see the rows that failed.

Comment: So then is there no way to specify that the date columns should be read by bcp as the SQL Server datetime type?

Comment: You could try a format file to match the fields.  bcp expects date as '2017-10-31' or '20171031'.  If you leave out '-c' option, then bcp will prompt you for the type of each column in database.  You can use DATE to see if it solves your problem.  The format file can be saved and used with a '-f' option.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Babu I've read about the format file but I'm not sure how to make/use it. I'm executing everything from Python(the goal is that this will be an automated process). Can you do me one last favor and post an example of setting up the format file then using it in the call statement? I really really appreciate your help! (Your help has given me more progress in a few hours than I've gotten in days on my own)

Comment: Hi Nick, generate the csv file and then from shell command line do the following - bcp <table> in <csv file> -S <server> -U <user> -P <password> -d <database> -t "\t" -r "\n" -e <errror file>.  This will prompt you to enter the SQL type for each column.  Notice the "-c" option missing in bcp.

Comment: You'll have an option to save the format file.  After saving the format file, you can then automate from python by using -f <format file> instead of -c in your script.

Comment: Thanks so much Babu! I meant to comment here earlier that I had figured out another way to solve my problem, but it's kind of hacky. I'll upload the dates as strings and then each time the script runs at the end it'll alter the column types within SQL Server. Then on subsequent runs it'll change them back to VARCHAR to upload the date-strings again. It's not pretty but it's working. Thanks so so much for your help today!!

Comment: Great.  I'm glad i could help you.

Comment: Hey @NicPayne, I believe if you just specify datetime as a format for the column in the final table, it should all work as desired. SQL will take care for casting, assuming that you do not have bad entries in the source data.

Answer (score 0):

'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test_table' just looks like invalid tsql syntax.
you can do something like this:

```
if (object_id('test_table') is not null) 
DROP TABLE test_table
```

Comment: MSSQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, POSTGRESQL all have slightly different but very similar syntax.

Comment: This is working in a sql statement that I execute with cursor.execute(), where cursor is the connection.cursor() object. Could you elaborate on how I could upload a pandas dataframe with this type of statement? I'm experimenting with the bcp as noted in the other answer but I'll try out a multitude of things since this process will be utilized more heavily in the future in our company and it'd be nice to have a wider breadth of knowledge.

Thanks!

Comment: The statement is supported in SQL Server 2016 onward.